# How to submit form after ajax success in Safari

Tags: javascript, ajax, safari, form-submit

I have a form with a submit button. And I put onclick="foo(event, this);" in the submit button for the submission.

I want to submit the form after ajax success.

Here my code :

```
<form id="form_a" action="destination.html">

  <input type="submit" id="submit_button_1" value="Submit button 1" onclick="foo(event, this);">

</form> 

<script type="text/javascript">

function foo(event, this_element)
{
    event = event || window.event;
    event_target = event.target || event.srcElement;

    //Prevent the immediate submission because I want submit after ajax success : 
    event.preventDefault();

    //Retrieve the submit button clicked :
    if(this_element.id == "submit_button_1")
    {   
            //Submit the form afer ajax success :

            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

            xhr.onreadystatechange = function()
            {
                if(xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200)
                {
                    //Retrieve the form object to submit :
                    form_a = document.getElementById("form_a");

                    //Submit the form 3000 ms later : 
                    setTimeout('form_a.submit();', 3000);
                }    
            } 

            //Send ajax request on server :
            xhr.open("POST", "server.php", false);
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            xhr.send("");
    }
}

</script>
```

This code doesn't work in safari. So How to submit form after ajax success in safari ?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to execute a string. The variable `form_` might not be available when it executes.

Your `setTimeout` should be like this, so that the form_a variable is accessed via `closure`.

```
setTimeout(function() {
   form_a.submit();
}, 3000);
```

Comment: Im using safari 9.0.3 and it works fine. Might be an issue with ur version. Place a debugger at `form_a = document.getElementById("form_a");` and see if it ever executes.

Comment: Yes I use safari 5.1.7. Can you try it on safari 5 and confirm me ?